# USER_AUTH and USER_END not being logged by openssh

Tags: arm, audit, openssh

I installed openssh with --with-audit=linux option and ssh is running properly (i.e to keep track of number of ssh login success and failure ).
But for some reason ssh always starts with login failure. 
When we give ssh login request(ssh@localhost), audit daemon always log it as login failure

I have logged into localhost on the first attempt

```
root@iWave-G22M:~# ssh localhost
root@localhost's password: 
Last login: Thu Jul 11 10:17:43 2019 from localhost.localdomain
root@iWave-G22M:~# exit
logout
Connection to localhost closed.
```

When I see aureport for the same  it shows one login failure by root
even though there were no login failure

```
root@iWave-G22M:~# aureport  -l

Login Report
============================================
# date time auid host term exe success event
============================================
1. 07/11/19 10:18:09 root 127.0.0.1 sshd /usr/sbin/sshd no 7
2. 07/11/19 10:18:12 -1 localhost.localdomain /dev/pts/0 /usr/sbin/sshd yes 8
```

openssh was build using bitbake

Comment: What version of OpenSSH do you use? The upstream version has quite  bare auditing support with linux so I would not be surprised if it would not be usable for aureport: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/audit-linux.c

Comment: openssh version is OpenSSH_6.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014  I built with bitbake openssh  and added --with-audit=linux to EXTRA_OECONF in openssh_6.5p1.bb file:  http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/openssh/openssh_6.5p1.bb?h=daisy

Comment: what do you mean when you say upstream version @Jakuje

Comment: That sounds like a quite an old version. But anyway in the link I provided, there is no significant auditing done, because the actual auditing in linux was never accepted upstream. See the upstream bug: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1402

Comment: can you send me the link to the openssh with audit support @Jakuje

Comment: In Fedora, we are using the following patch: https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/openssh/blob/master/f/openssh-7.6p1-audit.patch

Answer (score 0):

Try using ltracer, This will help you to generating login reports and export them into csv format.

This reports Active session, login history and Failure attempts made via ssh

https://github.com/sksaddamhussain/ltracer